# Matlab neural network training

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

What is the difference in performing the following codes? It is better to modify epochs in the training structure or put the training function in a loop?
Thank you

First code:

```
for(i=1:10)
    % Train the Network
    [net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
end
```

Second code:

```
net.trainParam.epochs = 200;
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the inputs and targets you provide for training are describing a model that is very hard to train, then there is theoretically no difference between the first and the second code.  This is assuming that your network is being trained and hitting the maximum number of iterations / epochs **for each iteration in the `for` loop**.

Assuming that this is the case, what would basically happen is that in your first piece of code, it would simply take the trained network at the previous iteration, and use that for the next iteration.  This is assuming that training **did not converge**, and it should simply pick up "where it left off" in terms of training.  In the second piece of code, you are setting the total number of iterations required for convergence in the beginning and letting the training happen only once.

If the situation arises such that it is very hard to train your network and we reach the maximum number of iterations / epochs per iteration in your `for` loop, then there will be no difference.

---

However, depending on your inputs and targets, training your neural network may take less than the maximum number of epochs you set.  For example, should you set your maximum number of epochs to ... say... 100, and it took only 35 epochs to train at the first iteration of your loop, the next iterations after that will not change the network at all, and so there will be unnecessary computation as a result.

As such, if your network is very easy to train, then just use the second piece of code.  If your network is very difficult to train, then simply setting the number of maximum epochs with the second piece of code and training it all in one go may not be enough.  As such, if you have a harder network to train, instead of setting a huge number of epochs which may take time for convergence, it may be wise to reduce the number of total epochs and place this into a `for` loop instead for incremental changes.

---

As such, if you want to take something away from this, use the second piece of code if you can see that the network is fairly simple to train.  Use the first piece of code with a reduced number of epochs but place it into a `for` loop for harder networks to train.